# Regex for email Validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate an email using the regular expressions. I alomost done but I am failing in one condtion alone which is "a '-' (hyphen) should not be followed by '@'". I tried in different ways but nothis worked. Below is the regex I am currently using.

```
regex = /^(?!.*\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9#$%&\*\+-/=\?\_`|~]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
```

PS : I know the the above regex stops for using two consecutive periods but its my project requirement :(

Please help me in validating for '-' followed by '@' and vice-versa.

Thanks,
Yeshwanth

Comment: You can pick a complete regex in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to add `(?!.*-@)` after your first lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add

```js
[a-zA-Z0-9#$%&\*\+-/=\?\_`|~]*[a-zA-Z0-9#$%&\*\+/=\?\_`|~]@
```

instead of

```js
[a-zA-Z0-9#$%&\*\+-/=\?\_`|~]*@
```

?

And is it OK to have a `+` or, say, a `#` right before the dog?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This works too :).. Yes, as per my requirements it is fine to have + or # before the '@'. I know this sounds odd.